# The output of a .txt file created in vi editor show all the text in one line

Tags: linux, text-files, vi

I have a log file for my scripts to get report that is report.txt file. When I see it in vi editor it is showing as I want it to be :

```
Sanity Report

Start time:Fri Mar 10 08:08:33 CST 2017

LABS:
1: lht1-u0 (172.28.152.240)
2: lht1-u1 (172.28.152.241)

BUILDS:

CCM: 455
AMM: 395
OEBase: 864 
ACS_DM: 569
AMS_DM: 707
TC Area TC Title Status

System-VM0 install ------------------------------------- Passed
System-VM1 install ------------------------------------- Passed
OpensSaf start ----------------------------- Passed
Verify alarmd server is -------------------------------- Passed
Product install of AMM ------------------------- Passed
Product install of AMM ------------------------- Passed
```

But when I open the actual text file in windows (this file should be email to a group of people) it shows all the text in one line. 
How can I change this?

Comment: I voted up and starred this question, I notice this too since I started using Linux. Even Android app do this (as you may be aware Android is based on Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to the end of line characters.
To my knownledge, on Unix and Windows, the convention differs.

DOS / Windows uses :

```
\r\n
```

Unix only:

```
\n
```

You need a way to convert your unix style end of line to the windows style.

The use of a regex engine can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. I found it here https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-files-from-linux-format-windows/ and I used awk 'sub("$", "\r")' uniz.txt > windows.txt worked well!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a file like this who does not have access to Linux, open the file with Wordpad (make a change??) and save it.

Next time you open it with Notepad it will appear normal.

Comment: I am posting this as a comment because I am not sure. I need to double check. But the command unix2dos might also fix this.